# Avoid error 'The selector of the component should be named kebab-case and include dash '

Tags: angular, tslint

How could I avoid error 'The selector of the component should be named kebab-case and include dash ' in Angular2, if I don't want to rename the selector? Is there any workaround?..

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import {CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA} from "@angular/core";

@NgModule({
    schemas: [
        CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
    ]
})
```

Comment: I would avoid this approach as it turns off nearly all compile-time checking of your templates.  I would only use this if you are truly using HTML Custom Elements inside of your Angular templates. (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements)

Answer (score 0):

This error is being generated by TSLint, using the `codelyzer` plugin.  This enforces the Angular styleguide recommendations for selectors: https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#component-selectors

As with most linting errors, there are ways to configure or ignore them.  Be sure to be deliberate about how and when you ignore linting errors.  Depending on your situation, you may want to handle this error differently:

- If all your components have this error, and have matching selectors, you can change the rules TSLint uses to check for errors in the TSLint.json file:

  ```js
  {
    "rules": {
      // The rules component-selector and directive-selector have the following arguments:
      // [ENABLED, "attribute" | "element", "prefix" | ["listOfPrefixes"], "camelCase" | "kebab-case"]
      "component-selector": [true, "element", ["cmp-prefix1", "cmp-prefix2"], "kebab-case"],
      "directive-selector": [true, "attribute", ["dir-prefix1", "dir-prefix2"], "camelCase"],
      ...
    }
  }
  ```

  *see [https://github.com/mgechev/codelyzer#recommended-configuration](https://github.com/mgechev/codelyzer#recommended-configuration_)*

  You can also configure the CLI to generate components and directives with the correct prefix at the bottom of your `angular.json` file:

  ```json
  {
    "schematics": {
      "@schematics/angular:component": {
        "inlineStyle": false,
        "inlineTemplate": false,
        "prefix": "myCustomPrefix",
        "styleext": "scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "myCustomPrefix"
    }
  }
  ```
- If you have a one-off component or directive you would like to exclude TSLint from checking, you can use the suppression comment:

  ```js
  // tslint:disable-next-line:component-selector
  ```
- If you would like to disable this checking completely, you can do so in `tslint.json`:

  ```json
  {
    "rules": {
      "directive-selector": false,
      "component-selector": false,
      ...
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: I wouldn't do that for each component.. it looks annoying and redudant. So, if you don't want to have prefix, just go to `tslint.json` and turn off the corresponding rule. In this particular case, change from `true` to `false` value of `"component-selector": [false, ... ]`.

Comment: @hastrb agreed.  I have updated my answer.  Thanks for the comment!